# Using ViewPager for Screen Slides

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to use `ViewPager` to implement screen slides.

In my start activity, there is one line like the following, which is also the error: "The constructor PhotoActivity.PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined"

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
mPagerAdapter = new PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

My `PagerAdapter` class:

```
private class PhotoSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PhotoSlideFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I found that if I change `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. It works. Why?

Comment: this may help you http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/tabnvigation-like-google-play-store-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
mPagerAdapter = new PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

instead of `mPagerAdapter = new PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());`

Comment: It gives me a new error: The method getFragmentSupportManager() is undefined for the type PhotoActivity

Comment: @FihopZz Your main Activity should extend `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Thanks, actually, I did it. It still gives me the same error. Just to make sure, we are talking about using `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: yeah, we are talking about `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: Try getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentSupportManager()